# application-side join example in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

by reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/application-joins.html#application-joins Now I understand I can get list of values then use them as a filter.

Since version 5.0 "filtered" query has been deprecated and now I've replaced with "bool" query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-filtered-query.html

I cannot find a way to populate result from the first query.

My first query:

```
GET /access_log/_search?size=5
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
        {"term":{"status":200}}
      ],
      "should": [
        {"match": {"request_1": "supporter-manager"}},
        {"match": {"request_2": "deploy"}}
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

So here I want all "user_id" that match above query and pass fill terms query in 2nd query

```
GET /access_log/_search?
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":{
        "terms":{
          "user_id":[]
        }
      },
      "should":[
        {"match": {"request_1": "rent"}},
        {"match": {"request_2": "start"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to populate result of 1st query into `"terms":{"user_id":[**here**]}` but I'm confused, How can I achieve this?

From my understanding field name must be specified so only possibilities would be passing in empty [] just like my query above or pass nothing (doesn't work either).

I've also tried using "must" clause and multi_match like this:
GET /access_log/_search?

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":{
        "multi_match":{
          "operator":"or",
          "fields":["user_id"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it keeps on giving me `"No text specified for multi_match query"` which I think is because I don't have "query" clause but then I am trying to fill that with list of user_id from query 1, again pass empty []?

So finally I get document that contain "request_1":"rent", "request_2":"start" and their "user_id" must be from query 1.